# Lemma 7.20 "Pseudo differential and singular integral operators" by Helmut Abels

Tags: operator-theory

I find myself studying the text "Pseudo differential and singular integral operators" by Helmut Abels and am stuck in some calculations.

[image]

How do you get the second inequality in 7.26? I have the following:

Let $a=|\lambda|$, $b=|\xi|$ and $\langle \xi\rangle=(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}$ then

\begin{align}(1+a^{1/m}+b)^{-m-|\alpha|}\leq a^{-\frac{m-m'}{m}}(1+b^2)^{\frac{-m'-|\alpha|}{2}}\nonumber\\
\Leftrightarrow a^{\frac{m-m'}{m}}(1+b^2)^{\frac{m'+|\alpha|}{2}}\leq (1+a^{1/m}+b)^{m+|\alpha|}\nonumber\\
\Leftrightarrow a^{1-m'/m}(1+b^2)^{\frac{m'+|\alpha|}{2}}\leq (1+a^{1/m}+b)^{m+|\alpha|}
\end{align}
where $m'\leq m$ implies $m'/m\leq 1$ then $0\leq 1-m'/m$.

Why $a^{1-m'/m}(1+b^2)^{\frac{m'+|\alpha|}{2}}\leq (1+a^{1/m}+b)^{m+|\alpha|}$ is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood inequality. It is basically because

1. $(1+b^2)^{1/2}\leq C(1+b)$ some $C$ constant
2. When expanding the right side, the term $(a^{1/m})^{m+|\alpha|}(1+b)^{m+|\alpha|}=a^{1+|\alpha|/m}(1+b)^{m+|\alpha|}$ will appear (and $1-m'/m\leq 1+|\alpha|/m,\ m'\leq m$), along with the fact that all terms are not negative.